# How to display multiple iframe as values in select attribute in angular2+

Tags: angular, select, drop-down-menu

i have many iframe src links, and i want the select attribute to display it . This is how i did it -

**component.html**

```
  <select name="numberOfChildren" class="selectBox">

   <option value="<iframe 
    src="http://10.0.0.4:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard?embed=true&_g 
    width="1200">">Graph one

    <option value="<iframe 
       src="http://10.0.0.4:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/79ffd6e0-faa0- 
       11e6- 
       947f-177f697178b8?embed=true&_g width="1200">">graph two

   </select>
```

The error that i get is :

```
   Unexpected closing tag "select". It may happen when the tag has 
   already been closed by another tag. For more info see 
   https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have- 
   implied-end-tags ("

   [ERROR ->]</select>
```

Please help me in showing a select attribute with values as iframe links.

Comment: try closing the option tag <option></option>

Answer (score 0):

YOu have not close `option` tag properly, Use this code

```
<select name="numberOfChildren" class="selectBox">

  <option value="<iframe
  src="http://10.0.0.4:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard?embed=true&_g
  width="1200">">Graph one</option>

  <option value="<iframe
  src="http://10.0.0.4:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/79ffd6e0-faa0-
  11e6-
  947f-177f697178b8?embed=true&_g width="1200">">graph two
  </option>

</select>
```

## Update

The way you are adding iFrame is wrong, instead of passing as value you need to call function and change srs of that iFrame like this

```
<select name="numberOfChildren" class="selectBox">
    <option value="getIframeValue('http://10.0.0.4:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard?embed=true&_gwidth=1200')">Graph one</option>
    <option value="getIframeValue('http://10.0.0.4:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/79ffd6e0-faa0-11e6-947f-177f697178b8?embed=true&_g width=1200')">Graph Two</option>
</select>
<iframe id="MyFrame1" name="MyFrame1" style="width: 1040px; height: 682px" src="Default.aspx"></iframe>

getIframeValue(src) {
  window.document.getElementById("MyFrame1").src = src
}
```

Comment: Unexpected closing tag "option". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("c="http://10.0.0.4:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard?embed=true&_g
                width="1200">">Graph one[ERROR ->]</option>

Comment: The method --> getIframeValue(src) .. do  i place it in <script> tag or will it work in component.ts as just a method

Comment: in a `component.ts` file as a method

Comment: error -->Property 'src' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

Comment: then typecast it into `HTMLIFrameElement`

Comment: (<HTMLIFrameElement>window.document).getElementById("MyFrame1").src = src